# Free Complex scalar field and separate conservation of particle and antiparticle number

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conservation-laws, symmetry, field-theory, antimatter

For a **free** complex scalar field, the difference between the number of particles and antiparticles is conserved by Noether's theorem. This constraint can be satisfied in two ways:

(i) Number of particles and antiparticle remains separately conserved in time, and therefore, their difference too.

(ii) By simultaneous creation of equal number of particles and antiparticles so that the number of Particles and antiparticles need not be conserved **separately**.  To illustrate, suppose one started with a system of $N$ particles and $M$ antiparticles at $t=0$, such that $N-M=$conserved. The time evolution of the system might be such that it can change $N$ to $N_1=N+n$, and $M$ to $M_1=M+n$ at a later time $t>0$, keeping $N_1-M_1=N-M=$conserved.

As far as Noether's theorem is concerned, it doesn't forbid any of the above two possibilities. But dynamics might forbid the second one.

If the possibility (ii) is forbidden by the dynamics in a free theory, why is that? How do I convince myself that the dynamics *separately conserves* particle and antiparticle number?

Comment: Yes, changes in total particle number are very much allowed. One of the main points of QFT is that the relativistic energies at which it is relevant allow for creation (and annihilation) of particles, as explained by e.g. Coleman himself [here](https://www.physics.harvard.edu/events/videos/Phys253).

Comment: Are you asking whether this is possible in a *free* field theory or in any field theory? If the former, then this is not possible simply because you can't draw a single Feynman graph that would contribute to such a process, if the latter, many ordinary scattering processes provide examples, so I'm confused what exactly the question is here.

Comment: @ACuriousMind- I mentioned 'free field' at the beginning of the question. But Noether's theorem says that cannot forbid such a possibility. Right? Because it says, only the difference of particle and antiparticle number needs to be conserved. So My question "*what forbids?*"

Comment: @Danu- Do you mean particle and antiparticle number can change separately in free theory too? I mean, does the dynamics allow it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an interacting theory, violation of individual particle and antiparticle number happens all the time via [pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production) and annihilation.  In a free theory, each is conserved individually.  The conceptual reason is that is the dynamics of a free theory is trivial - the initial condition can be decomposed via Fourier transform into a sum of plane waves, and the plane waves just pass right through each other without "talking," so no possible process could create or destroy a particle or antiparticle.  To see this formally, just consider the Hamiltonian for a free complex scalar field in equation (3.26) of [Srednicki's QFT textbook](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html) adapted to the complex case:

$$ H = \text{const.} + \frac{1}{2} \int \widetilde{dk}\ \omega(k) \left( a^\dagger(k) a(k) + b^\dagger(k) b(k) \right) := \text{const.} + \frac{1}{2} \int \widetilde{dk}\ \omega(k) \left( n^a(k) + n^b (k)\right),$$

where $a(k)$ annihilates particles and $b(k)$ antiparticles.  It's obvious that this Hamiltonian commutes with both of the total number operators $N^a := \int \widetilde{dk}\ n^a(k)$ and $N^b := \int \widetilde{dk}\ n^b(k)$, so both particle and antiparticle number are independently conserved.

Answer (score 1):

The possibility (ii) is forbidden by the dynamics only if the dynamics is to be covariant under symmetries from the Poincare group. This is explained in detail in Weinberg's book on quantum field theory (Vol.1).

In nonrelativistic theories with Galilei covariance, particle and antiparticle number are separately conserved.